# cross-browser CSS3 with generated png's

Tags: javascript, css, png

Just how stupid is the idea of javascript rendering gradients, rgba's, rounded corners, drop shadows and possible other CSS3 functions inside transparant png's to include with data url's?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: support for non-CSS3 browsers

Comment: My weapon of choice is graceful degradation.

Comment: Whenever anyone says they have problems "cross browser", they mean "it doesn't work in IE". Everything you mentioned works in every browser except IE.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, mine too, but everyone else just wants it "to look the same in IE".
@rob, yes you are right, it's supposed to add a little CSS3 support to old IE versions.

Comment: Yeah, it happens all the time. But at the end of the day, the user's experience is the most important fact. IE8 and lower are already slow enough, so hacking around to add all the advanced CSS3 stuff will make it even slower... Depends on the circumstances. We all make these decisions every day :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa you are absolutely right. But i'm gonna try it anyway, just for fun, to see if it will work ;)

Comment: If you really want to do it, I'd just say: don't reinvent the wheel. There are ready solutions out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better ways to support non-CSS3 browsers (ie IE) than this. I suggest [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/), which supports pretty much all the functionality you describe in IE.

CSS3Pie uses VML to do its rendering, which is makes for smoother gradients and curves, as well as being scalable. It also does rounded corners without interfering with the background of the element behind, which is an almost unavoidable problem with using graphics for founded corners.

If you are going to try rolling your own solution, I would suggest at the very least considering VML instead of PNG. If you go with a bitmap graphic solution, you'll have issues with elements where you don't know the size in advance (or worse, elements that are resized dynamicaly), and issues with backgrounds of elements behind the rounded corners.

Bottom line is that PIE is *by far* the best solution available for these features in IE. You're right, it does have some big issues, but there isn't any other solution that does a better job, and it's not for lack of trying -- there are a lot of alternatives, especially for rounded corners, but none of them come close.

Finally, I would say that whatever solution you go with, you need to be aware that IE<9 is a very slow browser. All these hacks (whether it's PIE or your own alternative) are great, but they will make it run even slower. Be careful about going too far and making your site look great but run too slowly. You might find that the most pragmatic solution is simply to let IE users see the site without all the bells and whistles.

Comment: used it before, but it behaves not like expected, especially not when having multiple CSS3 features on one element.
And drop-shadows for instance look nowhere like the ones in mozilla and chrome.

Comment: hmm, i guess you are right. I will just check out PIE to see if i can make any improvements to the project.
And save the idea of javascript generated inline png's for some other crazy idea ;)